# How do I ensure that openssl is using AES-NI acceleration?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, openssl

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, I checked that my processor does support AES-NI acceleration on all CPUs:

```
johndoe@mycomputer:~$ grep -m1 -o aes /proc/cpuinfo
aes
johndoe@mycomputer:~$ grep -o aes /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
4
johndoe@mycomputer:~$ lscpu | grep '^CPU(s):'
CPU(s):                4
```

How can I check that openssl using AES-NI?

Thank you,
Luckyrings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

To test if openssl is using AES-NI I found following information. You can't see after compiling that AES-NI is available for openssl, but you can perform performance tests with and without that feature.

Speed test with default settings:

```
openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-128-cbc
```

Speed test with explicit disabled AES-NI feature:

```
OPENSSL_ia32cap="~0x200000200000000" openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-128-cbc
```

The result the first line will run faster (almost double on my i7 cpu). So that conclusion is that AES-NI is used by default for openssl.

Comment: How is the OPENSSL_ia32cap line a valid command?

Comment: @VincentAlex: It is setting an environment variable before running the actual command.  There must be no spaces either side of the equal sign for the shell to recognise you are trying to set an environment variable as opposed to giving it the name of the command to run.